# 'in' keyword in python - identity or equality?

Tags: python

I am aware that `is` tests for identity and not equality of objects (eg. strings) in python. However I am curios whether `in` checks for equality or identity when used to check if an item is in a list / dict ?

I am unable to test this reliably as my interpreter seems to be be `intern`ing strings automatically at will (as you can see below even the `is` test passes implying only one copy of string was created in memory for all representations of `delta`):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'delta']
>>> if 'delta' in l:
...   print('K')
... 
K
>>> if l[2] is 'delta':
...   print('K')
... 
K
>>> if ('delt' + 'a') in l:
...   print('K')
... 
K
>>> if ('delt' + 'a') is l[2]:
...   print('K')
... 
K
```

Comment: The python compiler combines the string literals `'delt' + 'a'` into `'delta'` before checking for interned duplicates. Do something like `''.join('delta')` if you want a string generated at runtime that is not interned.

Comment: @tdelaney appreciate the comment on how interpreter checks for interned duplicates and how to avoid it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations), for *built-in container types*, `in` tests for both identity and equality. This is the relevant line:

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

Edit: updated the answer per juanpa.arrivillaga's comment, for non built-in container types, the behavior is implementation dependent.

Comment: Well, no. Not necessarily. This is the behavior for *built-in container data types*. The behavior for other types is up to the implementors. And it's important to note, this is meant to be an optimization

Comment: The referenced documentation is worth a read. `in` may consume an iterator. An `in` test with an open file handle will cause lines to be read until a matching line is found (or the file pointer ends up at EOF).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *"this is meant to be an optimization"* - Though as Raymond Hettinger [said](https://bugs.python.org/issue4296#msg75735) in a discussion about this: *The "identity implies equality" rule isn't just an optimization, it is a
deep assumption that pervades the language implementation.*